# mutual masturbation with right hand is it allowed?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it allowed to touch your spouse private part with right hand for like during masturbation. thank you is this permissible.

Answer (score 1):

Islamqa has an answer to this exact question:

"It is not haraam, rather, it is permissible, because it is a part of the enjoyment which Allaah has allowed. Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):
"Those who guard their chastity (.e., [private parts, from illegal sexual acts)
Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame." [al-Mu’minoon 23:5-6]"

see - https://islamqa.info/en/answers/826/masturbation-between-husband-and-wife

I don't know of any difference in opinion about this question, the noble ayah in surah al mu'minuun is quite clear that its permitted.